# Why can't we print ASCII values from 0 to 31?

Tags: c, ascii

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=31;i++)
        printf("%c",i);
}
```

when we try to run this code then nothing prints 
what is the reason for it ?

Comment: Some of the values are non-printable, but you can definitely print some of them (e.g., newlines).  Have you looked at an ASCII chart?

Comment: What output would you actually expect for `End of Transmission`? for `Vertical Tab`?

Comment: Read up on control-characters. As Stephen mentioned, some of them are well and truly printable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character  Here's #1 & #2 in DOS (as tadman reminded me): ☺☻

Comment: @enhzflep In DOS ([Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) not ASCII.

Comment: @tadman - thanks for that. I'd realized my mistake after reading your (great) answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C is printing them, but perhaps your terminal is not *displaying them*. This distinction is important because the terminal is responsible for interpreting the output of your program, printing letters, moving the cursor around, changing colors and such.

By historical convention the first 32 characters of the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) are considered "control characters", some of which are printable, some like backspace which move the cursor, others like BEL which can make your terminal beep.

Different terminals may display these differently, or not at all.

It's worth noting that ASCII pre-dates modern "glass" terminals and that these codes were used to move the print-head around on the page. Early machines used [teletypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) to communicate with them and a line-feed would crank down the paper one line, a carriage return move the cursor back to the start of the line, much like the physical [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) on a typewriter which would move the "carriage" back to the first column.

These were pretty elaborate elecromechanical contraptions that didn't have any modern circuitry in them, yet they could still process ASCII data, at least for those using ASCII, as there are other character sets like [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) that co-existed with ASCII.

As these characters were never intended to be printed, so they don't have a standard visual representation in ASCII.

With "extended ASCII", as used in DOS, there are [symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) defined for them because it seemed like a waste otherwise. These don't have control-code meanings, typically you write them directly to the console character buffer in order to see them.

Answer (score 2):

You can, it's just that most of them are [non-printable control characters that most shells ignore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters). If you pipe `stdout` to a file, the file will contain those characters, it's just the shell that doesn't know what to do with them. Some of them are handled by shells (e.g. the line feed and backspace characters) but others are just nonsensical (e.g. end of transmission, data link escape) and get ignored, or replaced with a different character for display (often a space or a question mark or the like).

Comment: Shell doesn't care so much as the terminal does.